# How to remove certain Aspell dictionaries?

Tags: spell-checking, aspell

If I run **aspell dump dicts**, I get the following dictionaries listed. If I just want to keep en_GB and en_US, how can I get rid of the others? I've been through the documentation [here](http://aspell.net/man-html/Working-With-Dictionaries.html#Working-With-Dictionaries) but don't see how to do this. (If it's relevant this is on both Linux and Windows.)

```
en
en_CA
en_CA-w-accents
en_GB
en_GB-w-accents
en_US
en_US-w-accents
es
fr-40
fr-60
fr
fr-80
fr_CH-40
fr_CH
fr_CH-60
fr_CH-80
fr_FR-40
fr_FR-60
fr_FR
fr_FR-80
```

Comment: Off topic for SO. This is a better fit for http://SuperUser.com

Comment: And no traction? This is the kind of question that may need a bounty to get interest and an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ignore the answer, if I understood the question wrong!** Or tell me more about what you mean.

**On Windows:**

If you want only a list of installed dicts you can get it with ..

```
aspell dicts | findstr /I en_
```

displays only the name of dicts that "en_" contain

On linux look at "grep"

**If you want to hide the dicts**

search for fr_*.multi and move all these files out of the Aspell dict folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I want to uninstall certain dictionaries so that when I run 'aspell dump dicts', it just shows the ones I want. Is it really as simple as just deleting some files manually? I imagined it would be more complex than that.

Comment: Yes, only remove all files "fr*.rws" and "fr*.multi" is enough.

Comment: Super! So obvious I missed it. :-)